# Guice: implications of field injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

My understanding of Guice is that:

- Constructor-level injection (`@Inject public class Widget(Dep one, Dep two)`) *implies* that Guice will always inject that constructor every time it is invoked through an `Injector`; and
- Method-level injection (`@Inject public void setDepOne(Dep one)`) *implies* that Guice will always inject that method whenever it is called, so long as the `Widget` object was created using the Guice `Injector`

Are these two assumptions correct? If not, please clarify!

So what I'm hung up on is: **what are the implications of field-level injection?**

```
@Inject private Dep one;
```

Does this mean that Guice will always inject the property when the object is created through the Guice injector? In that case I would imagine it conflicts with constructor-level injection.

For instance, does the following cause a conflict/error:

```
public class Widget {
    @Inject private Dep one;

    private Dep two;

    // Dep one already injected as a field!
    @Inject public Widget(Dep one, Dep two) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 24):

Guice will always inject all fields, methods, and any single constructor annotated with `@Inject`.  Keep in mind the constructor always gets injected first, so your annotated field will actually overwrite that injection.  Take this modified example:

```
class Widget {
    @Inject
    private Dep one;

    @Inject
    public Widget(Dep one) {
        this.one = one;
        System.out.println(one);
    }

    public void printDependency() {
        System.out.println(one);
    }
}

class Dep {}

public class MyMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector i = Guice.createInjector();
        i.getInstance(Widget.class).printDependency();

    }
}
```

When run, this will produce something like this:

```
com.example.Dep@63238bd2
com.example.Dep@69198891
```

Clearly two different objects.  The first line is the constructor; the second is the field injection.

I have not often found a use for field injection, except to reduce verbosity when writing Guice code samples.  In production code it's unwise because it makes code difficult to test.

Comment: Guice will always create a new instance of every dependency that it injects unless it finds a some other binding, such as singleton.

Comment: In this case the injected fields are private, which makes them difficult to access without using something like reflection.

Comment: could you provide link to office doc that explains this?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions are correct.  I believe that in this particular case Guice will inject `one` twice -- once through the constructor, once through the field -- if nothing else, because it can't know that they're going to the same field.