# Cannot find any HTTP Request Header here

Tags: java, playback

Getting below error for play java application. Please suggest me what mistake am i doing here. i dont understand if CSRF needs to be enabled if so i ahve added th application.conf the below line

play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter"

```
Cannot find any HTTP Request Header here

In /application/app/views/add_saving.scala.html:11
7        <div class="login">
8            <h1>Add saving account module </h1>
9        </div>
10        form(action = routes.HomeController.addSavingSubmit, 'class -> "form-horizontal", 'role->"form") {
11        @CSRF.formField 
12        @inputText(addSavingForm("AccountNo"), '_label -> "AccountNo",'class -> "form-control" )
13        @inputText(addSavingForm("FirstName"), '_label -> "First Name",'class -> "form-control")
14        @inputText(addSavingForm("LastName"), '_label -> "Last Name",'class -> "form-control")
15            <div class="actions">
```

This is add_saving.scala.html

```
@(addSavingForm: Form[models.Account])
@import models._
@import helper._
@main("Adding saving account") {
    <!-- this css class is not part of bootstrap but is defined in /css/style.css -->
    <section id="content">
        <div class="login">
            <h1>Add saving account module </h1>
        </div>
        form(action = routes.HomeController.addSavingSubmit, 'class -> "form-horizontal", 'role->"form") {
        @CSRF.formField
        @inputText(addSavingForm("AccountNo"), '_label -> "AccountNo",'class -> "form-control" )
        @inputText(addSavingForm("FirstName"), '_label -> "First Name",'class -> "form-control")
        @inputText(addSavingForm("LastName"), '_label -> "Last Name",'class -> "form-control")
            <div class="actions">
                <input type="submit" value="Create Account" class="btn btn-primary">
                <a href="@routes.HomeController.view_accounts">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
                </a>
            </div>
           }
    </section>
}
```

this is HomeController.java

```
public class HomeController extends Controller {

    private FormFactory formFactory;

    /** http://stackoverflow.com/a/37024198 **/
    //private Environment env;

    /** http://stackoverflow.com/a/10159220/6322856 **/
    @Inject
    public HomeController(FormFactory f) {
        this.formFactory = f;
    }
    /**
     * An action that renders an HTML page with a welcome message.
     * The configuration in the <code>routes</code> file means that
     * this method will be called when the application receives a
     * <code>GET</code> request with a path of <code>/</code>.
     */

    public Result index() {
        return ok(index.render());
    }
    public Result manage() {
        return ok(manage.render());
    }
    public Result statement() {
        return ok(statement.render());
    }
    @Transactional
    public Result view_accounts() {
        List<Account> AccountsList = Account.find.all();

        return ok(view_accounts.render(AccountsList));
    }
    public Result add_accounts() {
        return ok(add_accounts.render());
    }
    public Result close_accounts() {
        return ok(close_accounts.render());
    }
    @Transactional
    public Result add_saving() {
        Form<Account> addSavingForm = formFactory.form(Account.class);
        // Render the Add Product View, passing the form object
        return ok(add_saving.render(addSavingForm));
    }
    @Transactional
    public Result addSavingSubmit() {

        // Create a product form object (to hold submitted data)
        // 'Bind' the object to the submitted form (this copies the filled form)
        Form<Account> newSavingForm = formFactory.form(Account.class).bindFromRequest();

        // Check for errors (based on Product class annotations)
        if(newSavingForm.hasErrors()) {
            // Display the form again
            return badRequest(add_saving.render(newSavingForm));
        }

        // Save if new (no id) otherwise update product
        Account p = newSavingForm.get();
        if (p.getId() != null) {
            p.update();
        }
        else {
            p.save();
        }

        // Set a flash message
        //flash("success", "Account " + newSavingForm.get().getFirstName() + " has been created or updated");

        // Redirect to the  products page
        return redirect(controllers.routes.HomeController.View_accounts());
    }
```

this is Accounts.java

```
package models;

import io.ebean.Model;
import play.data.validation.Constraints;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import io.ebean.*;
import play.data.format.*;
import play.data.validation.*;
@Entity
public class Account extends Model {
    @Id 
    private Long AccountNo;
    @Constraints.Required
    private String FirstName;
    private String LastName;

    public Account(){}
    public Account(Long id, String fn, String ln){
        this.AccountNo=id;
        this.FirstName=fn;
        this.LastName=ln;
    }
    public static Finder<Long,Account> find = new Finder<>(Account.class);
    public Long getId()
    {
        return this.AccountNo;
    }
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return this.FirstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return this.LastName;
    }
    public void setAccountNo(Long i)
    {
        this.AccountNo=i;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.FirstName=firstName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName){
        this.LastName=lastName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by declaring the implicit Scala parameters again in my template and then providing them explicitly from Java as suggested in [this answer in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60272899/1937795).

So in `add_saving.scala.html` I would change the first line to:

```
@(addSavingForm: Form[models.Account])(implicit request: Http.Request, messages: play.i18n.Messages) {
```